# Begins with non-zero digit using nom?

Tags: rust, nom

I'm trying to write a markdown parser using `nom` and the EBNF shown [here](https://github.com/jbranchaud/js-play/blob/master/Markdown/grammar.md#ebnf). I'm a little stuck as how to express begins with non-zero digit when trying to parse a number.

```
Number = NonZeroDigit { Digit };
NonZeroDigit = "1" | "2" | "3" | "4" | "5" | "6" | "7" | "8" | "9";
Digit = "0" | NonZeroDigit;
```

**TLDR:** How do you implement `Number = NonZeroDigit { Digit };`

My current implementation looks like

```rust
    fn number(s:&[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], &[u8]> {
        let (_, head) = peek(1)(s)?
        if (is_non_zero_digit(head[0])) {
            return digit1(s)
        } else {
            return make_error(s, kind: ErrorKind.IsA)
        }    
    }
```

This one also seems a bit more simple and in line with `nom`.

```rust
fn number(s:&[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], &[u8]> {
    let (_, head) = peek(1)(s)?
    cond(is_non_zero_digit(head[0]),digit1)(s)    
}
```

I'm not sure if I want to be throwing an error of some sort? Because it could just be that this is not a number, but some kind of string like a date or time. Perhaps it doesn't even make sense to include the notion of a `Number` in the grammar for markdown?

Comment: What's the question? Does the EBNF not work? Do you have trouble throwing the error?

Comment: @ForceBru specifically, how do I express: Number = NonZeroDigit { Digit };